# Project tango Never called the OnXYZijAvailable Callback

Tags: google-project-tango

My Project tango has some problems.

1st. The OnXYZijAvailable callback is never called.
So sample code(point cloud) from github is not worked. (Point count always zero)

2nd. The back camera(RGB-IR) is seems always gray scale. How can I see color mode?

I guess back camera is broken or something wrong. Right??

Comment: a link pointing to the code you claim isn't working AND copying an excerpt here would be helpful to understand your issue.   Posting two separate questions will provide you with more relevant answers.

Comment: Hi can you check if the constructor app from playstore is working ? Link is [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projecttango.constructor&hl=en). Make sure you have the latest updates on your device as well. If the constructor doesn't work as well, please send an email to project-tango-help@google.com

Comment: @r4ravi2008 Hi, My tango pad had some problems. so the tango pad was exchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

1. restart the device. Google tango core is still very unstable.
2. make sure that the samples you're working with are aligned to the tango core version(check it on the samples your using Tags tab on github).
3. make sure that when you're configure the Tango object you're adding the depth perception like this:

   ```
   config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_DEPTH, true); // for getting point cloud
   mTango.connect(config);
   ```
4. about your grey-scale camera(which is very strange behaviour). Make sure you're adding color camera configuration like this:

   ```
   config.putBoolean(TangoConfig.KEY_BOOLEAN_COLORCAMERA, true);
   ```
5. make sure to add the dependency on the tango core also in the Manifest inside the application node(I totally missed it):

   ```
    <uses-library
       android:name="com.projecttango.libtango_device"
       android:required="true" />
   ```